# How to get the necessary data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

How to get the necessary data in Rails

[image]

http://localhost:3000/terms/1/phrases_terms

In the past, I've retrieved the following data:

model PhrasesTerms:

```
id, term_id, phrases_id
```

model term :

```
id , word, reding, meading
```

model phrase :

```
id , sentence
```

phrases_terms_controller.rb

```
 before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_term

  def index
    @phrases_terms = @term.phrases_terms
  end

  def new
    @phrases_term = PhrasesTerm.new
  end

  def create
    @phrases_term = @term.phrases_terms.new(phrases_term_params)
    if @phrases_term.save
      redirect_to term_phrases_terms_path(@term, @phrases_term), notice: "Phrases_Term was successfully created"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  private

  def phrases_term_params
    params.require(:phrases_term).permit(:term_id, :phrase_id)
  end

  def set_term
    @term = Term.find(params[:term_id])
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @phrases_terms.each do |phrases_term| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= phrases_term.id %></td>
        <td><%= phrases_term.term_id %></td>
        <td><%= phrases_term.phrase_id %></td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```

What I want to get out now is the "word" value of "term" and "sentence" of "phrases"x

schema.rb

```
create_table "phrases_terms", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "phrase_id"
    t.integer "term_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["phrase_id"], name: "index_phrases_terms_on_phrase_id"
    t.index ["term_id"], name: "index_phrases_terms_on_term_id"
end
```

routes.rb

```
 resources :terms do
    resources :phrases_terms, only: [:index, :create, :new]
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid N+1 query, in the controller use

```
def index
  @phrases_terms = @term.phrases_terms
end
```

and then in the view

```
<% @phrases_terms.each do |phrases_term| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= phrases_term.id %></td>
    <td><%= phrases_term.term.word %></td>
    <td><%= phrases_term.phrase.sentence %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```